# 403 Forbidden nginx when trying to run simple static html

Tags: ibm-cloud, pipeline, devops

I am trying to run a simple html page on the bluemix server. However I get 403 Forbidden error. I am using a manifest.yml to deploy.
This is what manifest.yml contains:

```
---
applications:
- buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/staticfile-buildpack.git
  host: helloworld-html-${random-word}
  name: lab6
  memory: 64M
  stack: cflinuxfs2
```

I am not sure what to do to fix this. This is how the file structure looks like. Also, why does my Javascript show the error 'document' is undefined. It works fine outside bluemix(eg in a browser).

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the structure of the app you are pushing? It works for me with simple sample like a index.html file in the root directory where I execute the push command. I think you try to access a directory with no index.html file.

Comment: I have added more details.

Comment: It seems that you are using the staticfile-buildpack. Please refer to this article: https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2014/08/29/deploying-static-web-sites/ to see an example of how it works on Bluemix

Comment: You need an index.html on root directory by default, or write a complete URL (with the correct path to the html file you want to load). About the JS syntax errors is a different question related to Eclipse Orion (add this first line to your JS file: /*eslint-env node*/ ).

Comment: Okay. Currently, my files are in the root directory right? Where do I write the URL?

Comment: I have added a index.html file and that works fine. I would like prompter.html to be displayed instead. How do I do that?

Comment: I have resolved this. Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To anyone who is having trouble with this, the name of the html file you want to display has to be index.html. It works when this is done. You also have to be in the root directory.